# SMTP delay when sending mail from Centos

Tags: centos, smtp

I am encountering long delays when trying to send mail with swiftmailer using 1and1's SMTP server. there is a 19 second delay everytime as shown below by tcpdump:

```
21:54:50.784747 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40875, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 94)
    my-website.co.uk.46086 > mrvnet.kundenserver.de.smtp: Flags [P.], cksum 0xc764 (incorrect -> 0x1ba9), seq 65:107, ack 193, win 115,     options [nop,nop,TS val 3384859388 ecr 1663195506], length 42
E..^..@.@.........~......`Y.+.E8...s.d.....
....c"YrRCPT TO: <enquiries@my-website.co.uk>

21:54:50.825354 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 4346, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    mrvnet.kundenserver.de.smtp > my-website.co.uk.46086: Flags [.], cksum 0x1c51 (correct), seq 193, ack 107, win 12, options [nop,nop,TS     val 1663195516 ecr 3384859388], length 0
E..4..@.<.f...~.........+.E8.`Y6.....Q.....
c"Y|....
21:55:09.786486 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 4347, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 66)
    mrvnet.kundenserver.de.smtp > my-website.co.uk.46086: Flags [P.], cksum 0x1fb6 (correct), seq 193:207, ack 107, win 12, options         [nop,nop,TS val 1663200256 ecr 3384859388], length 14
E..B..@.<.f...~.........+.E8.`Y6...........
c"l.....250 Accepted
```

Does anyone know why there might be a delay at this point in SMTP?

Comment: So the delay is between the sending MTA's "RCPT TO" and the destination MTA's "250 Accepted" reply. This could be tarpitting on the receiving side or a delay on the sending side, which would be configurable by you. If you have shell access, you can check if other MTAs, e.g. `mail`, have the same issue sending through 1and1.

Comment: @dartonw Using mail via the same SMTP server I also get a 19 second delay at the same point as above.

Comment: It sounds like tarpitting on 1and1's outbound relay. You may be able to get more info by connecting directly with telnet; see http://www.port25.com/how-to-check-an-smtp-connection-with-a-manual-telnet-session-2/ for an example. At this point, if the delay is a major concern, you should probably contact 1and1 support.